# canvas.getHeight() gives "wrong" numbers

Tags: java, android, canvas

When I am using

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

I need to know the lower edge of the canvas. Using

```
canvas.getHeight()
```

or

```
canvas.getClipBounds()
```

all give me values that are "under" my screen.
Zero is very well located at the top, below my Nav-Bar. But adding the height is far too "low" to be visible, just as if it was from the very top of the screen, not from the usable size below the nav bar.
I am trying to use this code in a fragment, which may somehow be the reason?
How do I get the lowest visible value on my screen?
Or how can I get the "absolute" value of my "zero-line"? I could then subtract it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the second part of my question: to get the absolute value, I used the following code:

```
    int coordinate[] = {0,0};
    this.getLocationOnScreen(coordinate);
    canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight() - coordinate[1];
```

So I can subtract the value to get correct values; nevertheless, is there another possibility?